# C# Searchable Lists - Replace SQL Tables

Tags: c#, custom-lists

I need to write an application that will perform some minor AD maintenance (basically taking a list of key/value pairs (AD username and a value taken from a SQL database) from another application in the form of a text file. The value in the text file is to be stored as a custom attribute per user in the AD. Unfortunately, the providing application does not produce a list of all users; only those users with a value in the field concerned, so any user who did have a value but now doesn't will not appear in the list - this means I can't use the list to directly remove the attribute value, only to add or modify it.

If I could use SQL Server I would just have a table of all users and a table of users with values (supplied by the other applications) and use a SET statement to blank the attribute in all users who do not appear in the provided list, then another SET to populate the value in all users who do appear in the provided list.

I'm new to C# and I don't know the best method to use to emulate that SET/SET functionality; I can read the AD to get all users, and I can read the file to get the users who now have a value to set, but I'd ideally like to read them into two "tables" and use some sort of comparison to set and unset the attribute as required. I can't think of a web search query to find what I need (my Google-fu is weak for subjects I'm new to) so any suggestions of the best way to proceed would be very gratefully received.

**Example:**

Original AD list:

```
AD Username    Madeup Attribute
------------------------------
abc1           value1
bcde           {no value}
fgh            value2
```

Provided list:

```
AD Username    Madeup Attribute
---------------------------------
bcde           value3
fgh            value4
```

Resulting AD values:

```
AD Username     Madeup Attribute
--------------------------------
abc1           {no value}
bcde           value3
fgh            value4
```

Apologies if my explanation is not brilliantly clear - another one of my "(many) weaknesses, it seems.

Comment: So you can read the AD and you can read the file? It's just connecting the two that you're stuck on? How are you temporarily storing the values from the file as you read them? If you give us a bit of the code you've got - it gives us more of a frame of reference.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a merge op, it's a replacement? File always wins over AD? Read the file into a `Dictionary<T,U>`, enumerate the AD, if dictionary doesnt contain the ad user, set the attrib value null, if dictionary does contain then update the value and remove the dictionary entry. At the end of the op decide what to do with any remaining dictionary entries (Add to AD?)

Comment: Each user has one or multiple attributes in file?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan - sorry but I don't have any code yet as I couldn't decide on an approach to use. Like I said, I'm new to this and my usual method isn't available to me.

Comment: @CaiusJard - yes, that's it; the file always wins, but has incomplete data. Any user without the required attribute would not have an entry in the file. I could just blank the attribute for all users and then process the file but I wanted something a bit more elegant and all-round _better_ than that.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad - one attribute only; it's a custom attribute if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Dictionary` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) would be an easy way to do this.

In the first step, read in all the user ID's and add an entry with a null as value

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new  Dictionary<string, string>();

// For each user in the AD list:
dic.Add(username, null);  // Could als use empty string "" instead of null

// For each user in the provided list:
dic[username] = userattribute;
```

Then you can reference the attributes later and get the attribute for a user by using

```
string attr = dic[username];
```

Comment: Hi Christopher - I've never used a dictionary before but if it's directly searchable then I think it may be the way forward here. In my head I'm thinking that the dictionary would be filled with the users who have the attribute set in the file and then I would sequentially read the AD, blank the attribute for all users who aren't in the dictionary and update those who are - does that sound right?

Comment: Hi again - it works perfectly, thank you for the suggestion. I'll definitely remember dictionaries for the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can read file into `Dictionary<string, string>` and update AD users like this:

```
        //Key is username and Value is attribute
        var userAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
        //fill dictionary with file

        //get list of AD users
        var activeDirectoryUsers = new List<YourADUserModel>();

        //map the made up attribute from dictionary
        activeDirectoryUsers.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.MadeUpAttribute= userAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == x.Username).Value;
        });
```

Comment: Hi Saeed - your answer looks interesting but I'm afraid I needed to get a result out as soon as possible and the last bit of the code above I would need to research a bit more. Thanks, though - it'll give me something more to learn and that's always a good thing :-)